# Is there any data-input attribute able to use in bootstrap-table?

Tags: json, input, bootstrap-table

Is there any data-input  attribute able to use in bootstrap-table to insert data into db?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok! As far as I know you can't do that bootstrap. You need to use Javascript to create json and post it to service you are using.